# Find the conditional p.d.f given the joint density function

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Good evening, I'm trying to solve **Exercise 12.3**:

> [image]

Could you please verify if my proof looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

- $y \le 0$. Then $f_Y (y) = 0$.
- $0 < y \le 1$. Then $1/y \ge 1$. It follows that $$f_Y (y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{2x^2y} \textbf{1}_{(1,\infty)}(x) \textbf{1}_{[1/x,x]}(y) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_{1/y}^\infty \frac{1}{2x^2y}  \, \mathrm{d} x  =  \frac{-1}{2xy} \Big|_{1/y}^\infty = \frac{1}{2}$$
- $y > 1$. It follows that $$f_Y (y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{2x^2y} \textbf{1}_{(1,\infty)}(x)  \textbf{1}_{[1/x,x]}(y) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_{y}^\infty \frac{1}{2x^2y}  \, \mathrm{d} x  = \frac{-1}{2xy} \Big|_{y}^\infty = \frac{1}{2y^2}$$

---

**Update:** Thank you @Chinny84 for pointing out my misunderstanding of the requirement of the question. I fixed it here.

Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x >1 \, \text{and} \, y \in [1/x, x] \}$.

- $(x,y) \notin A$. Then $f_{Y|X=x} (y) = 0$.
- $(x,y) \in A$. It follows that $$\begin{aligned} f_{Y|X=x} (y) &= \frac{\frac{1}{2x^2y}}{\int_{ 1/x}^{x} \frac{1}{2x^2y} \, \mathrm{d} y}   = \frac{\frac{1}{2x^2y}}{\frac{\ln y}{2x^2} \big|_{1/x}^{x}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2x^2y}}{\frac{\ln x}{x^2}} = \frac{1}{2y\ln x}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: You found the marginal distribution for $y$ - but I believe you want $f_{y|x}(y|x)$?

Comment: Hi @Chinny84, Thank you so much! I have just fixed my attempt. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @Akira Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: Many thanks for your verification @heropup ^o^